# Prevent memory leaks on reinitialise

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, mutex, memory-mapped-files

I have a class that can open memory mapped files, read and write to it :

```
public class Memory
{
    protected bool _lock;
    protected Mutex _locker;
    protected MemoryMappedFile _descriptor;
    protected MemoryMappedViewAccessor _accessor;

    public void Open(string name, int size)
    {
        _descriptor = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(name, size);
        _accessor = _descriptor.CreateViewAccessor(0, size, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
        _locker = new Mutex(true, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), out _lock);
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _accessor.Dispose();
        _descriptor.Dispose();
        _locker.Close();
    }

    public Byte[] Read(int count, int index = 0, int position = 0)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[count];
        _accessor.ReadArray<Byte>(position, bytes, index, count);
        return bytes;
    }

    public void Write(Byte[] data, int count, int index = 0, int position = 0)
    {
        _locker.WaitOne();
        _accessor.WriteArray<Byte>(position, data, index, count);
        _locker.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

Usually I use it this way :

```
var data = new byte[5];
var m = new Memory();
m.Open("demo", sizeof(data));
m.Write(data, 5);
m.Close();
```

I would like to implement some kind of lazy loading for opening and want to open file only when I am ready to write there something, e.g. :

```
    public void Write(string name, Byte[] data, int count, int index = 0, int position = 0)
    {
        _locker.WaitOne();
        Open(name, sizeof(byte) * count); // Now I don't need to call Open() before the write
        _accessor.WriteArray<Byte>(position, data, index, count);
        _locker.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

**Question** : when I call "Write" method several times (in a loop) it will cause member variables (like _locker) to reinitialise and I would like to know - is it safe to do it this way, can it cause memory leaks or unpredictable behavior with mutex?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you open in the write method using a lock, it's safe to close before you release the mutex.

When you are dealing with unmanaged resources and disposable object, it's always better to implement IDispose interface correctly. [Here is some more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347660/how-to-write-a-destructor-for-a-class/30387119#30387119).

Then you can initialse Memory instance in a using clause

```
using (var m = new Memory())
{
// Your read write
}
```